# how to add value to build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to do with shared preference?
or,

Add a database column value to build.gradle?

```
buildConfigField "String", "secretKey", "\"here should be the value i want\""
```

Comment: You could store your secrets in the local.properties file or create another .properties file. build.gradle is used to build the apk, so obviously you won't be able to access shared prefs or database column value through it. See https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android

Comment: Thanks, How do i store and access that value from local.properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root directory create a file, for ex: apikey.properties

```
SECRET_KEY=YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

In your build.gradle to read the apikey.properties

```
def apikeyPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("apikey.properties")
def apikeyProperties = new Properties()
apikeyProperties.load(new FileInputStream(apikeyPropertiesFile))

android {
  defaultConfig { 
    buildConfigField("String", "SECRET_KEY", apikeyProperties['SECRET_KEY'])
  }
}
```

You can access the field in your with the `BuildConfig` object.

```
String secretKey = BuildConfig.SECRET_KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. write code in `gradle.properties`

```
YOUR_ACCESS_PARAMS = "YOUR_VALUE"
```

2. write code into app level `build.gradle`

```
android{
    ...
     buildTypes.each{
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'ACCESS_PARAMS', YOUR_ACCESS_PARAMS
    }
}
```

3. the generated BuildConfig.java is as follows:

```
public final class BuildConfig {  
    public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");   
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx";   
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";  
    public static final String FLAVOR = "";  
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;  
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0.0";  
    // Fields from build type: debug  
    public static final String ACCESS_PARAMS = "YOUR_VALUE";  
}
```